# why do cp command get error without noting add -e option?

Tags: scala, nginx, sbt, dockerfile, centos7

### Premise · What I want to realize

I've getting an error into writing a Dockerfile, so I'm worried about a getting error.
That command is `cp`.

### testing environment

- base container image [centos:7](https://registry.hub.docker.com/layers/centos/library/centos/centos7/images/sha256-1f832b4e3b9ddf67fd77831cdfb591ce5e968548a01581672e5f6b32ce1212fe?context=explore)
- My laptop is MacBook Pro (it may not need info, isn't it?)

### What I did

the Dockerfile is here,

```
FROM centos:7 # Official centos image. this is a comment for asking here.

ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk \
    SCALA_HOME=/usr/local/scala \
    SCALA_VERSION=scala-2.13.0

WORKDIR /usr/local/lib/

RUN : " *** nginx install ***" \
  && { \
        echo '[nginx-stable]'; \
        echo 'name=nginx stable repo'; \
        echo 'baseurl=http://nginx.org/packages/centos/$releasever/$basearch/'; \
        echo 'gpgcheck=1'; \
        echo 'enabled=1'; \
        echo 'gpgkey=https://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key'; \
        echo 'gpgkey=https://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key'; \
     } > /etc/yum.repos.d/nginx.repo \
  && yum install -y nginx \
  && yum install -y rsyslog \
  && rsyslogd \
  && cp /usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service /etc/systemd/system/ \
  && nginx -version \
  && : " *** JDK install ***" \
  && JAVA_HOME=${JAVA_HOME}/bin \
  && PATH=$PATH:${JAVA_HOME}/bin \
  && java -version \
  && javac -version \
  && : "*** Scala install ***" \
  && wget http://downloads.typesafe.com/scala/2.13.0/scala-2.13.0.tgz \
  && tar zxvf scala-2.13.0.tgz \
  && ln -s ${SCALA_VERSION} scala \
  && mkdir ${SCALA_HOME} \
  && mv ${SCALA_VERSION} SCALA_HOME \
  && SCALA_HOME=${SCALA_HOME}/bin >> /etc/profile.d/scala.sh \
  && PATH=$PATH:${SCALA_HOME}/bin >> /etc/profile.d/scala.sh \
  && source /etc/profile.d/scala.sh \
  && cd \
  && scala -version \
  && : "*** sbt install ***" \
  && curl https://bintray.com/sbt/rpm/rpm | tee /etc/yum.repos.d/bintray-sbt-rpm.repo \
  && yum install -y sbt \
  && sbt -version \
  && ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Tokyo /etc/localtime \
  && yum clean all \
  && mkdir -p /usr/share/app

WORKDIR /usr/share/app

EXPOSE 80
```

### Problems occurring · Error messages

the getting error is,

```
cp: invalid option -- 'e'
Try 'cp --help' for more information.
```

umm.., I've completely understand the error.
I haven't cp alias too.

Could you please help me?
If you need more information, feel free asking me.

Regards,
K

Comment: Try changing your `cp` command in Dockerfile to `cp -- /usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service /etc/systemd/system/`
Some details can be found here https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/problem-with-mv-and-cp-771043/ or here - https://askubuntu.com/questions/913526/ls-invalid-option-2

Comment: @RayanRal
Thanks for your kind reply. I've tried it you taught method. exactly the error was resolve. But I've gotten a new error has occuredl again。。。 . ```

What Can I do another metod?
are Thare another things ?

Comment: @RayanRal Sorry, I mistook. I tried your method and this error resolved!! Thank you again＼(^o^)／

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had the same error as you because i wrote the command as below

sudo find /home/usersdata -type f -user mark -exec cp -p -parents {} /official ;

- the parameters parents should --parents instead of -parents

For some reasons the error does not provide explicitly what is wrong.

Hope it helps you